# Get a value of float from a series float in PineScript

Tags: compare, pine-script, series

I have a 'series float' that was given from `ta.atr()` function. I need to compare the last element of this 'series float' to another float number. But anything I do, I can not get the element as a float number to make the comparison. What can I do?

Here is part of my code that I'm dealing with the problem:

```
int min_dev = 1
ATR = ta.atr(length) *100 /close[1] 
var float dev_threshold = min_dev * ATR[1]

if (math.abs(dev) >= dev_threshold)
    iline = line.new(iLast, pLast, index, price, color = color.blue, xloc = xloc.bar_index)
```

In the code above, the comparison does not complete, and `if` doesn't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `var` keyword, this code will be executed only once, at the first bar of your chart.

Maybe you should remove the `var` keyword no?

var being executed at the first bar and referring to ATR[1] being the previous value of ATR, I'm not sure if there is any previous value to fetch here actually....

Comment: At first, I had no `var` keyword. and there was no difference there. The `if` didn't execute at all.

Comment: so that means the dev variable is never above dev_threshold
Maybe plot the two variables and try to debug that way

Comment: Thanks, I did it again with your guidance and it worked perfectly. I don't know what happened before that it didn't work. Thanks again.